# python 3.4 list comprehension - calling a temp variable within list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of dictionaries and I would like to extract certain data based on certain conditions. I would like to extract only the currency (as int/float) if the currency is showing USD and more than 0.

```
curr = [{'currency': '6000.0000,EUR', 'name': 'Bob'}, 
        {'currency': '0.0000,USD', 'name': 'Sara'}, 
        {'currency': '2500.0000,USD', 'name': 'Kenny'}, 
        {'currency': '0.0000,CND', 'name': 'Debbie'}, 
        {'currency': '2800.0000,USD', 'name': 'Michael'}, 
        {'currency': '1800.0000,CND', 'name': 'Aaron'}, 
        {'currency': '2500.0000,EUR', 'name': 'Peter'}]
```

Results:

```
usd_curr = [2500.0000, 2800.0000]
```

This is what I have done.

```
usd_curr = [line for line in data if ',USD' in line['currency']]
usd_curr = [float(elem['currency'].split(',')[0]) for elem in curr if float(elem['currency'].split(',')[0]) > 0]
```

The list works but my question is really this - is there a better way to use a variable inside the list comprehension so it will look something like this:

```
usd_curr = [var = float(elem['currency'].split(',')[0]) for elem in curr if var > 0]
```

Comment: No, you can't create variables inside the comprehension.  You'll either have to repeat the expression as in your first example, or use two comprehensions.  The latter option, with one comprehension to extract the data and another to filter out the zeros, may be more readable.

Comment: `usd_curr` gives all `currency` having value `>0`. `usd_curr`==> `[6000.0, 2500.0, 2800.0, 1800.0, 2500.0]`.

Comment: @Praveen - That is true if I do not want to get the currency by USD. In this case I want to get the currency if the string contains the word 'USD'.

Comment: @BrenBarn - Thanks. Would it be faster to split it into 2 list than repeating the expression?

Comment: If you use two comprehensions as @BrenBarn suggests, don't make a list of the first one, but an iterator instead (with parentheses instead of brackets).

Comment: @muraveill why dont make it an answer

Comment: A good rule of thumb is: when your list comprehension starts getting too complicated to be immediately obvious rewrite it as a plain `for` loop. Then you won't have any restrictions on assigning to variables. If you still want to inline the value then rewrite as a `for` loop and extract it out to a generator. That way you get both readability and flexibility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no nice syntax to do that using comprehensions.  You could use an inner generator to generate the values to cut the repetition, but it'll get unreadable real quick the more complex it gets.

```
usd_curr = [
    float(val)
    for val, val_type in (elem['currency'].split(',') for elem in curr)
    if val_type == 'USD' and float(val) > 0
]
```

I'd suggest using a named generator instead.

```
def get_currency_by_type(curr, curr_type):
    for elem in curr:
        val, val_type = elem['currency'].split(',')
        if val_type == curr_type and float(val) > 0:
            yield float(val)

usd_curr = list(get_currency_by_type(curr, 'USD'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do two comprehensions, but not allocating a list for the first one, just creating an iterator instead:

```
temp = (float(elem['currency'].split(',')[0]) for elem in curr)  # an iterator, not evaluated yet
usd_curr = [x for x in temp if x > 0]
```

You could also use `map` and `filter` instead, functional style, which is probably the code that is generated by the above anyway.